# Some basic questions after looking at the CI sourcecode

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was just looking at the CodeIgniter source code and I came across a couple of things that I can't seem to figure out; I'm not sure what they mean, and since they're mostly like one or two symbols it makes it hard to search on both google and stackoverflow for them.

One thing that I came across quite a lot is this:

```
$this->config =& get_config();
```

I have never really encountered the `=&` (or mostly the `&`) in PHP before. What does this mean exactly? Are they assigning an instance of `get_config` to `$this->config`? I assume the `$this->config` comes from a declaration at the top of the file where it says `var $config = array();`

I went looking for the `get_config()` function, and I found the following line:

```
function &get_config($replace = array())
```

Here, my question is pretty much the same: what does the `&` stand for and what does it do? I see these two things (`&` and `=&`) a lot throughout the CI core files.

Something else I was wondering about is their commenting 'style'. Every function starts with a comment block, here's an example:

```
 /**
 * Set HTTP Status Header
 *
 * @access  public
 * @param   int     the status code
 * @param   string
 * @return  void
 */
```

Is this generated by some plugin or library? It sounds like a lot of hassle to do this manually. I haven't checked out stuff like PHPDoc, but could this be something similar (or PHPDoc)? It seems useful, if it generates that automatically? Heehee.

Onto the next question. I see different functions prefixed by underscores. There's the obvious `__construct` but there's also functions like `_set_default_controller();` and `_set_routing();` Do these underscores have any special meaning? I know the double underscore is used for something called 'magic methods' (I'm thinking about `__get` and `__set` since those are the ones I've used myself). Do they have any 'special' technical meaning or is this pure semantics? Enlighten me if possible.

Last but not least, in the controller core file I saw this:

```
class CI_Controller {

    private static $instance;

    public function __construct()
    {
        self::$instance =& $this;
                // goes on
```

The line of interest here is `self::$instance =& $this;` What does this mean? Does it set `$this`to an instance of itself (wiiiiiild guess, haha), so we can use $this? Or does that make no sense? Actually it doesn't, since in the very basic MVC boilerplate I use myself for basic websites, I use $this without any of that advanced stuff.

Can anyone offer some insight here? I'd be grateful. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: For all your questions about `&` (references):http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: Oh, thanks. I had absolutely no clue what it was called and searching for '&' didn't get me very far ;) I'll make sure to read that!

Comment: That's what that topic is indeed for: SO cannot be searched for that kind of thing  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The `&` operator there is assigning a value by reference, meaning further use of this variable will reference the *original* value, not the assigned one. Reference (no pun intended): http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php
2. The comments are [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/) style, they aren't generated themselves, but can be handy in creating docs with phpdoc or other software, and picking up expected params and return values in an IDE.
3. The underscore *usually* means the method is `private`. When used in a CI controller, it means the method is inaccessible by url. Related: [What's the deal with a leading underscore in PHP class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663350/whats-the-deal-with-a-leading-underscore-in-php-class-methods)
4. You are pretty much correct. The function `get_instance()` will return the `$instance` property of `Controller`.

Comment: Thank you. I'll make sure to check out the links you provided. I think I understand the basics of the reference thing now; not quite sure why you would use it though.. buuut if it's anything like pointers in C, it makes sense that I don't get it, because I never understood that either ;D

Comment: @cabaret: Quick example: I assign `$foo = 1;`, `$bar =& $foo;` and then increment `$foo`. `$bar` is now equal to 2 because it's value references the original `$foo`.

Comment: And $foo? Is it still 1 or 2 aswell? Because if it's 2 aswell, why not just use $foo? Probably missing the point here, haha.

Comment: @cabaret: Yes, they are both equal to 2. That was just to help you understand references, not a good real-world example. Think of it in the context of the huge CI object, we want to usually reference the original object and pick up on when it changes, not copy the object to a new one in it's current state.

Comment: Oh, okay. Well, thanks. I'll go read the documentation! And thanks for getting to this, I've learnt a lot from you since I joined this site :)

Comment: FYI none of this is explicitly related to Codeigniter, it's regular PHP.

Comment: Yeah, I realise that; just got to it from looking at the CI source, really.

Comment: I find that looking at the CI source really demystifies it and makes me want to write my own framework. Yeah right, like I have time for that! I wish. Glad you're reading it and getting a good understanding of how it all really works, it will help you get a lot more out of Codeigniter.

Answer (score 3):

`&` is for passing something by reference, meaning any changes you make to the variable that you assigned it to will affect the original variable. It essentially sends it the memory location instead of the value.

Here's the [php.net documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) for references.

Example:

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = &$foo;
$bar = 'bar';
echo($foo);
//Should output "bar"
```

Why can this be useful?

```
function everythingButFirst($s){
    return(substr($s,1));
}

function everythingButFirstV2(&$s){
    $s = substr($s,1);
}

//First example: Without reference
$str = "abcde";
$str = everythingButFirst($str);
//Will set $str to bcde

//Second example: With reference
$str = "abcde";
everythingButFirstV2($str);
//Will set $str to bdce
```

It saves a bit of typing with assignment, you see. Much easier to call a function than call a function and assign it to a variable.

Comment: Kind of like the & used for pointers in C? Kinda confused. ;(

Comment: I'm not very familiar with C, but I'd assume it's similar usage, yes.

Comment: So, just to make sure I understand this right: you declare $foo and pass a string 'foo' to it; then you declare $bar and assign the address (memory location) of $foo to it; then, when you change $bar to 'bar', it actually updates it in the memory location of $foo, and $foo will then return 'bar' because we updated it through $bar refering to &$foo? Correct?

Comment: Yes. And if you echo `$bar` as well, it'll be the same as `$foo`.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I don't yet see how that is useful though, but I guess I'll go read up on it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It's mostly useful in functions. I'll edit my answer to give a function example.

Answer (score 3):

- For all your questions about `&` (references):[what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)(SO)
- For all your questions about comment blocks look at [phpDocumentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/)
- For questions about the preceding underscore look at [naming conventions](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.naming.php)
- The CI_Controller looks like a [Singleton](http://www.php.net/singleton)