# Are these underscored PHP functioned ever called?

Tags: php, cakephp, naming-conventions

Inherited an old CakePHP site and I'm trying to figure out what some functions do. I have several functions that have the same name as another function but with an underscore first, e.g. `save()` and `_save()`. However the function `_save()` is never called in any context, though `save()` is.

I read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663350/whats-the-deal-with-a-leading-underscore-in-php-class-methods) and it looks like it's from an old worst-practices exercise, but that doesn't really explain why it's in my code; you still have to call `function _save()` as `_save()` right? If there's no calls to `_save()` is it safe to remove?

I want it gone, even the `save()` function wasn't supposed to be there, rewriting perfectly good framework functionality. It looks like an older version of the same function, but there's no comments and I don't know if there's some weird context in which php/Cake will fall back to the underscored function name.

Here's the code for the curious. On closer inspection it appears the underscored functions were old versions of a function left in for some reason. At least one was a "private" method being called (from a public function of the same name, minus the underscore...):

```
    function __save() {
    $user = $this->redirectWithoutPermission('product.manage','/',true);

    if ($this->data) {
        $this->Prod->data = $this->data;
        $saved_okay = false;
        if ($this->Prod->validates()) {
            if ($this->Prod->save()) $saved_okay = true;
        }
        if ($saved_okay) {
            $product_id = ($this->data['Prod']['id']) ? $this->data['Prod']['id'] : $this->Prod->getLastInsertId();
            if ($this->data['Plant']['id']) {
                $this->data['Prod']['id'] = $product_id;
                $this->Prod->data = $this->data;
                $this->Prod->save_plants();
                $this->redirect('/plant/products/'.$this->data['Plant']['id']);
            } else {
                $this->redirect('/product/view/'.$product_id);
            }
            die();
        } else {
            die('did not save properly');
        }
    } else {
        die('whoops');
    }
}


function save() {
    $user = $this->redirectWithoutPermission('product.manage','/products',true);

    if ($this->data) {
        $this->Prod->data = $this->data;
        if ($this->Prod->validates()) {
            $this->Prod->save();

            $gotoURL = isset($this->data['Navigation']['goto'])?$this->data['Navigation']['goto']:'/';
            $gotoURL = str_replace('%%Prod.id%%', $this->data['Prod']['id'], $gotoURL);

            if (isset($this->data['Navigation']['flash'])) {
                $this->Session->setFlash($this->data['Navigation']['flash']);
            }
            if (isset($this->params['url']['ext']) && $this->params['url']['ext']=='ajax') {
                $value = array(
                    'success'=>true
                    ,'redirect'=>$gotoURL
                );
                print $this->Json->encode($value);
            } else {
                $this->redirect($gotoURL);
            }
        } else {
            $value = array(
                'success'=>false
                ,'message'=>"You have invalid fields."
                ,'reason'=>'invalid_fields'
                ,'fields'=>array(
                    'Prod'=>$this->Prod->invalidFields()
                )
            );
            print $this->Json->encode($value);
        }
    } else {
        $this->redirect('/products');
    }
    die();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure since I don't play with CakePHP for some years, but underscores are commonly used to differ local functions from inherited ones.

Comment: But in that case you still have to call the underscored function directly, right? I've confirmed that there is _no_ single call to this function (and others). I really just need to know if in any context a call to `save` would hit this function instead, as that function _is_ called

Comment: Doesn't CakePHP have profiling?

Comment: Not per se, but in testing I haven't been able to get the function to call...I'll have real profiling once I'm on PHP 5.3 but that's not yet

Comment: Can you paste the suspect code?

Comment: It's possible that `_save()` is called by legacy applications built on top of CakePHP, and is now provided by cake for backwards compatibility.

Comment: I added an example of code. It's not provided by cake, it's all code made by our developer. There's a `__save()` method in one of the CakePHP models, but it's for `saveAll()` which we aren't using to my knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had hoped to learn whether or not some convention applied to this situation, but from testing I've found the functions are *not* called which is really the answer to the question I asked.

Comment: Functions with a single, leading underscore are just normal functions. ["A valid function name starts with a letter or underscore, followed by any number of letters, numbers, or underscores."](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php) One exception are the [magic-methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php), which start with two underscores.