# Interacting with extended libraries in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

As a side note, I know the Javascript library is experimental but I'm doing some work with it nonetheless.

I have extended both the Javascript library and the jQuery library in CI.

```
MY_Javascript extends CI_Javascript
```

and

```
MY_Jquery extends CI_Jquery
```

Independently these work almost perfectly, If performing a click function with:

`$this->javascript->click('#target', code_to_run());`

the javascript library essentially just calls:

```
$this->js->_click($target, $code)
```

In keeping with this syntax, my extended javascript and jquery libraries contain `function dialog()` and `function _dialog()` respectively.

However, when I call `$this->javascript->dialog()` when it references `$this->js->_dialog()` it's giving me an internal error. But if I change the contents of `$this->javascript->dialog()`to just `return "Test return"` everything works fine.

I've also done `return print_r($this->js);` which doesn't show any of the _functions.

If I understand how extending a library in CI works everything should still work out.

Or perhaps this has nothing to do with CI and is a PHP paradigm that I've just completely missed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer lies here here [What's the deal with a leading underscore in PHP class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663350/whats-the-deal-with-a-leading-underscore-in-php-class-methods). Although I can't devote enough time to confirm that those functions are private. Interesting to know about the underscore though.