# PHP function name starting with ONE underscore

Tags: php

I am writing a huge PHP class and starting to realise that I lack some knowledge of a few PHP coding conventions that could help me organise a bit.

My question is about using ONE underscore before a PHP function's name (not two, I know what two underscores do) :

- Is it actually a PHP convention for private functions ?
- Is it in any way interpreted as being something specific by certain frameworks, template engines, etc ? (like /** is caught by PHPdocumentor)
- Is there any merit apart from immediately being able to tell if a function is public or private ?

Comment: There are **many** varying conventions used in PHP applications.  You're on the right track though... a lot of folks use underscores to indicate that a function is private.

Comment: use php codesniffer for checking your php file

Comment: You can find the answer below :)

[this is to clarify the meaning of underscores in php function in old OOP in PHP4  ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663350/whats-the-deal-with-a-leading-underscore-in-php-class-methods

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Not being sure of how to write "good" code is the most annoying part of being an amateur : I'm always double-guessing myself and end up feeling ashamed at showing my code... ;-)

Comment: It's true that the question might have been answered by the "what's the deal with a leading underscore in PHP class methods", but only partially, as I wanted to know about points 2) & 3) above, too.
Anyway, thanks all for your answers !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The use of leading underscores is somewhat dictated by opinion, though it could be seen as a form of Hungarian notation, a "crutch" that programmers use to know what type of function it is.

Disregarding magic methods, double underscore would have been used to indicate private methods whereas a single underscore would mean a protected method.

This convention was introduced because PHP 4 OOP didn't have visibility modifiers such as `protected` and `private`. With the introduction of PHP 5, you no longer need this.