# Why underscores(_) is used in functions like function _save_cart in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I saw many tutorials underscores (_) are used in function.

But I don't know why it is used and how can I use ?

Like this :

```
function _save_cart()
{

}
```

Comment: Question has been answered here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/663350/whats-the-deal-with-a-leading-underscore-in-php-class-methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In objective languages functions and variables names seperate with capitalize char, forexample: saveCart(), getCart(), ...

But in functional languages people use underscore and i think it comes from C posix standarts/notations.

C language doesn't support private and protected keywords so people generally use one or two underscore as pre extension for make the function private or protected.

Php firstly created as a functional language after a long time ZEND added object oriented features. So many people used to write it like a functional language. And so if you see a function like _save_cart you can understand that: an old school php coder make this function protected or private with posix way.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Codeigniter documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/controllers.html#private-methods),

> Prefixing method names with an underscore will also prevent them from being called. This is a legacy feature that is left for backwards-compatibility.

I have used it in cases when I need a helper-type function to be publicly accessible within the code, such as for validation, but not accessible from a browser.

Answer (score 0):

Underscores are a perfectly valid character in PHP function names and you can use them like any other.

Generally, a function that starts with an underscore means that the function is meant to have a hidden visibility. [Here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/1402c3d8b46906670b2131d7121ac8ea9ee26c71/wp-admin/includes/credits.php#L45) is an example with the WordPress source code.

At the same time, an underscore might just be used to reduce the chance of a naming conflict or just because the author thought it would be more aesthetically pleasing. [Here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/f75f20edb2a34bb508188b55be70069c75d5ae79/wp-includes/l10n.php#L160) is another example with WordPress (a function that is meant to be used publicly):

As mentioned in the comments there is another answer regarding methods. Underscores in front of functions and methods are considered bad practice. For more information you can refer to the [PSR-2 Coding Style Guide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/).

Answer (score 0):

There are 4 naming conventions:

1. **with_underscores**
2. **PascalCased** ( first letter is caps and second word is caps / **Pascal+Cased** / **ContactUs**)
3. **camelCased** ( first letter is small caps and second is caps / **cammel+Casesd** / **contactUs**)
4. **lower_case** ( all the letters are small caps / **contact_us**)

> But in CI we use **PascalCased** and **lower_case**

---

**In Codeigniter**

```
---------------------------------
| Classes       |   PascalCased |
| Methods       |   lower_case  |
| Properties    |   lower_case  |
| Functions     |   lower_case  |
| Variables     |   lower_case  | 
---------------------------------
```

---

Read this

1. [Codeigniter Variable Names](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html#variable_names)
2. [PSR-2: Coding Style Guide](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)

Comment: i can think of a few more naming conventions than that